# how to convert Calculated column in SAS query to Amazon athena query:

Tags: sas, amazon-athena

```
type here
```

I have to convert sas query -> Amazon athena query.

In ONE table, after I create column 1(fruit color), and use it to make column 2(Warm_cold).
I did in SAS by using "Calculated" before the column 1 name  but it doesnt work in amazon Athena.
Can you conver below sas query to amazon Athena?

---

**SAS**

proc sql;
create table first_appli as
select

select

```
Case
When Fruit=’Apple’ then ‘red’
When Fruit=’banana’ then ‘yellow
When Fruit=’blueberry’ then ‘blue’
End as “fruit_color”

Case
When CALCULATED “fruit_color” in (“red”, “yellow”) Then “warm_color”
When  CALCULATED “fruit_color” in (“blue”) Then “cold_color”
End as “Warm_Cold”
```

from tale 1
quit;

---

Amazon athena

select

```
Case
When Fruit=’Apple’ then ‘red’
When Fruit=’banana’ then ‘yellow
When Fruit=’blueberry’ then ‘blue’
End as “fruit_color”

Case
When  “fruit_color” in (“red”, “yellow”) Then “warm_color”
When  “fruit_color” in (“blue”) Then “cold_color”
End as “Warm_Cold”
```

from tale 1

---

- 

I want to make column 2 (bigger category), by using column1 (detail category).
but in the <same table> . I don't want to use another SELECT to make seperate column 2

Answer (score 0):

Either repeat the code that calculates the value.

So if you had:

```
   select var1,var2,var2+var3 as new1
        , case when (calculated new1 > 10) then .....
```

Change it to:

```
   select var1,var2,var2+var3 as new1
        , case when (var2+var3 > 10) then .....
```

Or derive the values in a subquery first

```
   select var1,var2,new1,case when (new1 > 10) then ...
   from (select var1,var,var2+var3 as new1 from ... )
```